# Word/Phrase request: Describing the action of "writing down something you remembered"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Say you've read a poem by William Shakespeare. You liked it very much so you remembered it by heart. Now you can *recite* it, i.e., read it aloud from your memory, or, you can write it down accurately without checking up the source.

Is there an English word or phrase to describe the **latter action**? In Chinese we have a word called 默写 that does the job. It functions both as a verb and a noun. If I were to translate it into English, what is the colloquial way to express it?

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the latter action, we write things down *from memory*. I can't think of a more concise way to say that.

We also recite (speak out loud) something from memory.

Answer (score 0):

I would use 'to quote' - http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quote?searchDictCode=all. Hope this works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of idiomatic phrases you could use:

> I have committed that poem to memory.

or

> I know that poem by heart.

or

> I know that poem so well that I could recite it in my sleep.

I imagine there are many others.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

I think the phrase most commonly used is "quoted by heart" i.e. verbatim (Latin).

To quote verbatim means to quote **word for word**. This does not only mean the quoting of a conversation word for word (i.e. verbatim), but the recitation of poetry or text word for word.